# Is it a good idea to edit WordPress within Eclipse?

Tags: linux, ide, eclipse

A friend and I are building a WordPress website. He has already customised a WordPress theme, and I can view the new site in an Internet explorer and edit it within the WordPress tool. He has sent me the source code.

I need to do many modifications, and as a developer, I want to do that with Eclipse instead of the WordPress tool (is it a good idea?)

Under Linux, I have already installed Eclipse, PDT, XAMPP, and can run very basic PHP+CSS projects.

Does anyone know what are the following configuration steps?

Comment: Nobody seriously doing this would ever only do this with the WordPress tools/editor - never, it would just be crazy. From the looks of it you have everything you need, I'm doing my projects under Linux with Eclipse too. Not exactly sure what additional configuration you mean, for WordPress you will need a MySQL database - its part of XA**M**PP though - table, but then I would say you can start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely should use a proper code editor like Eclipse instead of the web interface. Another good idea that will save you tons of headaches is to install git and create a local repository for you changes. Commit your changes every time you complete a feature or fix a bug and you'll have a nice way to rollback if you make a mistake somewhere.